# What is intended behavior for += with 2D arrays in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is intended behavior for += with 2D arrays in JavaScript?

```js
let  matrix = new Array(3).fill(new Array(3).fill(0));
matrix[0][0] += 1;
console.log(matrix); //[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]
```

Why the output is

`[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]]`

and not

`[[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]`

Is this intended behavior?

Comment: `Array.fill` will place *the same* array in every slot. So you are changing `[0]` but `[1]` and `[2]` also point at the same object.

Comment: Pasted your code into a snippet and the output I get is `[
  [
    /**id:2**/
    1,
    0,
    0
  ],
  /**ref:2**/,
  /**ref:2**/
]`